# Multiples tables aggragation without subqueries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, view, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have a "Main" table and multiple associated tables (let's call then T1, T2, etc...). All associated tables are related to MAin in N-1. Now I have a statistic query that collect aggregate informations on the associated tables. Here is the query example:

```
SELECT *
    Main.*,
    Sub1.*,
    Sub2.*,
    ...
FROM Main
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT T1.main_id, SUM(T1.col1) as stat1, AVG(T2.col2) as stat2
    FROM T1
    GROUP T1.main_id
) Sub1 ON Sub1.main_id = Main.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT T2.main_id, COUNT|AVG|SUM
    FROM T2
    GROUP T2.main_id
) Sub2 ON Sub2.main_id = Main.id
LEFT JOIN ( T3 ... )
```

As you can see, I have been using separate GROUP BY subqueries and I join everything together with a set of LEFT JOIN. Everything is working fine until now, but...

I need to create a VIEW based on that query, and as you maybe know, it's not possible to use subqueries in MySQL VIEWs. So the question is: How to rewrite such query without using subqueries?

Note: I know that I can use several sub VIEWs for each subquery. But this is an option I prefer to avoid.

Comment: You can make each of the sub queries a view in their own right, and then have this query / view join against those views rather than directly against the sub queries.

Comment: Hi @Kickstart, thanks for the tip. It's an option I already think about it, but I prefer to avoid it, for maintenance and cleanliness of the VIEW stack. Thanks anyway

Comment: Afraid I can't see another way to do it that would be vaguely efficient (although I sympathise with your desire to avoid creating many extra views). You could probably merge in 1 sub query into the main query and still get acceptable results, but trying to do it with several would make a mess of the aggregate fields. I suppose a possible (but slow) solution would be to use co related sub queries for each of the aggregate values in your main SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Create seperated view for each subquery then you can call directly view. it will work.
or Use mysql workbench to connect mysql DB. and run create view script from mysqlworkbench. It will work.

Example:

```
create or replace view SUB1 as SELECT T1.main_id, SUM(T1.col1) as stat1, AVG(T2.col2) as stat2
    FROM T1
    GROUP T1.main_id;



create or replace view SUB2 as SELECT T2.main_id, COUNT|AVG|SUM
    FROM T2
    GROUP T2.main_id;

SELECT *
    Main.*,
    Sub1.*,
    Sub2.*,
    ...
FROM Main
LEFT JOIN Sub1 ON Sub1.main_id = Main.id
LEFT JOIN SUB2 on Sub2.main_id = Main.id
```

....
....

Comment: While this post snippet may solve the question, including an explanation along with some code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future